# Converting an array to string and back

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array which is expressed in this way:

```
$id = $values['ids'];
```

Result:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "4" [1]=> string(1) "6" [2]=> string(1) "7" [3]=> string(1) "8" [4]=> string(1) "9" [5]=> string(2) "10" }
```

Originally, I was imploding this array so that I could pass it off as a value to use in $_POST:

```
$id = implode(",", $values['ids']);
```

Result:

```
string(12) "4,6,7,8,9,10"
```

In my $_POST page, I need to revert back to the original array, but when I use explode, I now get this result:

```
$id2 = explode(" ", $id);
//array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "4,6,7,8,9,10" }
```

I think the issue is how I am imploding this in the first place - it's making the individual values as one string, but not sure what to do in order to get the result I need.  I need to pass the array on as a value, and then put it back into the original format that it was in as the array.  Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: Please add your current code/attempt into your question.

Comment: What delimiter did you use when you tried `explode()`?

Comment: Actually - I think I answered my own question.  If I find that I am still having issues I will re-ask this with the code so as to not cause confusion.

Comment: @Wes Just add your code to your question and add more details if you think you have to specify your problem more.

Comment: I've updated it to reflect the issue.  I was thinking these needed to be ints but they don't.  Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @Wes Then you only use the wrong delimiter for explode and you need to change space to a comma

Comment: Thanks!  Pedro's answer helped me to realize that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with `intval` as callback:

```
$nums = "4,6,7,8,9,10";
$intsArray = array_map('intval', explode(',', $nums));
var_dump($intsArray);
```

---

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(4)
  [1]=>
  int(6)
  [2]=>
  int(7)
  [3]=>
  int(8)
  [4]=>
  int(9)
  [5]=>
  int(10)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I just answered my own question.  It was in the way I was using explode.  Should be:

`$id2 = explode(',', $id);`

And not:

`$id2 = explode(" ", $id);`

I'll give credit to Pedro who caused me to realize this when he pasted his example.

Comment: Thanks for the mention but array `$id2` still contains strings and not ints as the OP want, use `var_dump($id2);` to confirm that.

Comment: @PedroLobito OP doesn't need integers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281507/converting-an-array-to-string-and-back#comment48661440_30281507 And ^^ this is OP...

Comment: Hi @Rizier123, almost at 30k ;) The question was updated, the original contained a request for an array with ints. I didn't realize this was the OP.... I probably miss a coffee...

Comment: @PedroLobito Well I had the same answer prepared as you have, but I didn't posted it, because the: `string(12) "4,6,7,8,9,10"` was suspicious for me. (FYI: ^ See the blue box around the user name? That's the indication, that the post is from OP)

Answer (score 0):

Easily you can use `json_encode` and `json_decode` functions. For example:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$b = json_encode($a);
var_dump($b);

$c = json_decode($b);
var_dump($c);
```

that result of run is:

```
meysampg@freedom:~/www/testFunc$ php json_deEncode.php 
string(11) "[1,2,3,4,5]"
array(5) {
  [0] =>
  int(1)
  [1] =>
  int(2)
  [2] =>
  int(3)
  [3] =>
  int(4)
  [4] =>
  int(5)
}
```